# how to create an algorithm in java which gives a date that is seven days later than it should be

Tags: java

Ques is :
Write a Java program that will continuously ask (i.e in a loop) a user to input the year from 1900 to 2099 to compute for any Easter Sunday. There are four years—1954, 1981, 2049, and 2076—for which the algorithm gives a date
that is seven days later than it should be. Check for these years and subtract 7 from the day of the month

This is my code that I've tried..
The problem is that it's constantly displaying the same date even when I keep inputting another year..

```java
package assignment1;
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class assignment1
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Input year from 1900 to 2099:");
            int year=input.nextInt();

            int a = year % 19;
            int b = year % 4;
            int c = year % 7;
            int d = (19 * a + 24)%30;
            int e = (2 * b + 4 * c + 6 * d + 5)%7;
            double easter = 0;
            int date = (int)Math.pow((22+d+e), easter);
            int dateeaster=0;

            while ((year<1900)&&(year>2099))
            {
                System.out.print("Invalid year. Please try again.");
                year=input.nextInt();
            }

            if (year==1954||year==1981||year==2049||year==2076)
            {
                if (date>31)
                {
                    date=date - 31;
                    dateeaster=date-7;
                    System.out.print("Easter Sunday in:"+ year + "is April" + dateeaster);
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Easter Sunday in :"+ year + "is March" + date);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if ((year>1900) && (year<=2099))
                {
                    if (date>31)
                    {
                        date=date-31;
                        System.out.print("Easter Sunday in: "+year + "is April "+ date);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.print("Easter Sunday in: "+year + "is March" +date);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your title doesn't agree with your question.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the `LocalDate` class? If so, do.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
double easter = 0;
int date = (int)Math.pow((22+d+e), easter);
```

You are always rasing `22+d+e` to the power of zero which is always 1.